# By file commit message in Xcode version control

Tags: xcode, git, xcode6, commit

During a commit in Xcode, I can write a commit message. Is it somehow possible to write a commit message per file that is changed? Of course I am not changing all the project files at once all the time and it would be convenient that each file has it's own change log. Right now all files get the same change log and I have to mention which change effected which file.

Comment: The only way to do this would be to commit the changes to each file individually, which would be a lot more work than listing the changes in the commit message. Perhaps you could keep a text file in the working copy that lists the changes, which could be committed along with the code so you have it stored in the repo as well? Not sure that'd save you any work though.

Comment: @orbrey Is this a general thing or Xcode specific?

Answer (score 2):

*Right now all files get the same change log and I have to mention which change effected which file.*

If you just want to be able to tell which files were changed in a change(commit) you can

1. Open a terminal, navigate to the project directory and do

   ```
   $ git log --name-only
   ```

This gives an overview of which commit affected which files. This can of course be narrowed down to show it for a specific commit

```
$ git log commitHash --name-only
```

2. Via Xcode

   Open the Source Control menu and select history

   [image]

   The commit log is now shown. Click on any commit's *Show X modified files* to see a list of files that were changed, and a full diff.

[image]

Diff snapshot:

[image]